# I have multiple boxes in vagrant.d. Which one will it start?

Tags: cygwin, vagrant, virtualbox

I have 3 VM's located in...

```
/home/username/VirtualBox VMs
```

If I do, `vagrant up`, which one will it start?

My Vagrantfile doesn't mention multiple VM's, nor seems to point to any particular VM directly.

Comment: filename with `default`

Comment: All 3 folders are formatted as: username_default_14200#######_####

Comment: That's not username, that's folder name. Seems you up the vagrant instance from your home directory.

Answer (score 0):

Please read this :https://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/multi-machine/

> By default in a multi-machine environment, vagrant up will start all of the defined machines. The autostart setting allows you to tell Vagrant to not start specific machines. Example:

```
config.vm.define "web"
config.vm.define "db"
config.vm.define "db_follower", autostart: false
```

> When running vagrant up with the settings above, Vagrant will automatically start the "web" and "db" machines, but will not start the "db_follower" machine. You can manually force the "db_follower" machine to start by running vagrant up db_follower.